# using Pusher with java and laravel

Tags: java, laravel, pusher

Could you please tell me if I can develop a realtime application using both java and laravel, in fact I'm trying to send data to the pusher using java then display trades using laravel, I've already done this using only laravel to send events and to listen also, but now I need to do the first part with java, is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, yes. You simply trigger an event with Java, and you subscribe to that event with JavaScript, which you can implement in a Laravel application. As long as you use the same channel and application keys, you should be fine.

**Trigger with Java**:

```
pusher.trigger("my-channel", "my-event", Collections.singletonMap("message", "hello world"));
```

**Subscribe with JavaScript**:

*Embed this into your Laravel application*

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
    alert('Received my-event with message: ' + data.message);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome :-). Tip: please accept the answer to let other people know this answer helped you out.